# In Solr, how to use edismax with filter queries (but without a default field)?

Tags: solr, edismax

I have an edismax query with faceting enabled. I haven't specified a default field (neither in the select clause nor in the solrconfig.xml), as I only want to search on the fields specified in the 'qf' parameter. (I have the impression that if I **do** specify a default field, that field is also taken into account).

Here's the query:

```
/select?q=david&defType=edismax&qf=firstname^1+lastname^10&facet=true&facet.field=organization
```

So far everything works as expected: I get some results and there are also some results from the faceted search, e.g.

- "UZ Leuven" (18)
- "OLV Aalst" (8)
- ...

When I now click on one of the organizations, I want to search only within the set of documents that belong to that organization, hence the use of a filter query. However, when I add such a 'filterQuery' (fq), Solr complains that

> no field name specified in query and no default specified via 'df'
>   param.

So does that mean I **do** have to add some kind of 'catch-all' default field? But this doesn't seem logical, as all search fields are already specified in the 'qf'?

Here's my query:

```
/select?q=david&defType=edismax&qf=firstname^1+lastname^10&fq=organization:UZ+Leuven
```

And here is the output from the query:

```
{
  responseHeader: {
    status: 400,
    QTime: 1,
    params: {
      q: "david",
      qf: "firstname^1 lastname^10",
      wt: "json",
      fq: "organization:UZ Leuven",
      defType: "edismax"
    }
  },
  error: {
    msg: "no field name specified in query and no default specified via 'df' param",
    code: 400
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `organization:"UZ Leuven"`, as it's complaining about a missing field name for `Leuven`. The standard query syntax for the `fq` parameter is the lucene syntax.

If you want to use the edismax/dismax query syntax for the `fq` parameter, you'll have to tell Solr [to use the edismax parser](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/DisMax-query-parser-syntax-for-the-fq-parameter-td496556.html) through LocalParams:

```
fq={!type=edismax qf=$fqqf}organization:UZ Leuven&fqqf=field1 field2 field3
```

or possibly

```
fq={!type=edismax qf='field1 field2 field3'}organization:UZ Leuven
```

Comment: But i want to search on all 'qf' fields as well, not just on the 'fq' param. Do you mean the 'fq' parameter cannot be used with edismax?

Comment: In that case you've got to tell Solr you want to use the edismax parser instead through LocalParams, which should work. See my updated answer for two possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks, i will test your answer on Monday. Still I'm not sure whether a filter query is used in your example. Maybe an extra clarification of what I am trying to do: the fq param is used to retain all users of a certain organization (also that query can be cached, i.e. it's a filter query). The resulting collection will then be searched on first and last name via the edismax-specific 'qf' params. Does that make sense (I'm quite new to solr, maybe I'm missing something)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need the edismax query parser for that - using just `fq=organization:"UZ Leuven"` should do just what you need for the filter query. The query itself will still use the edismax parser if that's what you've supplied as `defType` for your query. According to your description a regular filter query with the standard lucene syntax should be enough to limit the result set, while the query itself (`q=`) can use the edismax query parser as you want.

Comment: Thanks again! I have updated the question with some more info. Do you see some things I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're still missing "" around your value in `fq`.